# puppet with multiple NFS mount on same server

Tags: linux, linux-networking, puppet, nfs

I have few NFS mount points on the same server but different directories.
ex:

```
    x.x.x.x:/stats   /data/stats
    x.x.x.x:/scratch   /data/scratch
    x.x.x.x:/ops   /data/ops
```

But when i try to run puppet it adds following to my fstab. (wrong mount assignment)

```
x.x.x.x:/scratch   /data/stats       nfs     defaults,nodev,nosharecache     0       0
x.x.x.x:/scratch   /data/ops  nfs     defaults,nodev,nosharecache     0       0
x.x.x.x:/scratch   /data/scratch     nfs     defaults,nodev,nosharecache     0       0
```

It is using the last mount option on all mounted partitions. so i did a little bit of research and found the following bug.

```
 https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/DOCUMENT-242
```

Then added nosharecache option, but still no luck.
this is my puppet code

```
class profile::mounts::stats {
  # Hiera lookups
  $location = hiera('profile::mounts::stats::location')
  $location2 = hiera('profile::mounts::stats::location2')
   tag        'new_mount'

 file { '/data/stats':
ensure  => directory,
owner   => 'root',
group   => 'root',
mode    => '0755',
require => File['/data'],
tag     => 'new_mount',
}

  mount { '/data/stats':
ensure  => mounted,
fstype  => 'nfs',
device  => $location,
options => 'defaults,nodev,nosharecache',
require => File['/data/stats'],
tag     => 'new_mount'
}



file { '/data/ops':
  ensure  => directory,
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'mail',
  mode    => '0775',
  require => File['/data'],
  tag     => 'new_mount',
}

 mount { '/data/ops':
ensure  => mounted,
fstype  => 'nfs',
device  => $location,
options => 'defaults,nodev,nosharecache',
require => File['/data/ops'],
tag     => 'new_mount',
}

file { '/data/scratch':
ensure  => directory,
owner   => 'root',
group   => 'mail',
mode    => '0775',
require => File['/data'],
tag     => 'new_mount',
}

 mount { '/data/scratch':
ensure  => mounted,
fstype  => 'nfs',
device  => $location2,
options => 'defaults,nodev,nosharecache',
require => File['/data/scratch'],
tag     => 'new_mount',
}

 }

 }
```

My hieara lookup is as follows

```
 profile::mounts::stats::location: x.x.x.x:/stats
 profile::mounts::stats::location2: x.x.x.x:/scratch
```

why it is causing some unexpected behavior ?